# Variable cannot be declared or modified

Tags: javascript, class, variables, ecmascript-6, let

I have a question about JavaScript. When I declarate new variable and assign to it new instance of class, if error is thrown variable is getting completely unusable.

**Code below should throw an error**

```
class MyClass {


    constructor (config) {

        this.someProperty = config.someProperty || '';

    }


}

let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
```

If I try to assign something to it, JavaScript will throw an error.

`myClassInstance = '123'`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myClassInstance is not defined

Then I tried to define variable

`let myClassInstance = '123'`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'myClassInstance' has already been declared

Variable also cannot be deleted. Is there anything that we can do with that issue? I'm just curious, of course I will handle passing undefined as config to constructor.

EDIT: I also tried using var, I can then reuse myClassInstance. I wonder why if I use let that variable cannot be deleted, declarated or new value cannot be reassigned.

EDIT 2: **I can handle passing undefined or pass empty object. Just pure curiosity what happens in JS console with that variable, also code will not execute if you paste everything at once**

Comment: Try using var instead of let.

Comment: not helping, I tried

Comment: Show us some more code. I am pretty sure, the issue must be of scoping

Comment: However if I assign new instance of class using var, then I can reuse that variable, I wonder what happens with let

Comment: @Kenny just paste code to chrome debug or something similar, and then you can see what I mean

Comment: There is an error in your "config.someProperty", since config is not passed to the constructor. The empty string "" will be only assigned if the left side is null or undefined. But config object itself is undefined. Write let myClassInstance = new MyClass({someProperty:null});

Comment: I'm getting errors before I even try to set anything. What exactly is supposed to be in `config.someProperty`?

Comment: Just string, I know that error is thrown before assigning anything, but if you paste blocks of my code to inspector or chrome debug, something happens with that variable and it is not declareted, but cannot be declareted too.

Comment: @AlanMroczek What is the issue you're trying to address here? If your code throws an error, the code flow would jump out of whatever block it's in, so it doesn't matter if the variable becomes completely "unusable", because I don't think there's any situation where you would be able to try to use that variable after the error was thrown.

Comment: Yes, I know, because of that I can handle passing undefined or pass empty object. Just pure curiosity what happens in JS console with that variable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Running code in the interactive console creates a contrived situation that couldn't happen in typical code execution.

Firstly, what you're seeing isn't specific to errors thrown in class constructors. You can observe the same behavior if you execute any `let` statement where the RHS throws an error:

```
let myVariable = "".boom();
```

The [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) talks about a "temporal deadzone" where a variable declared with `let` exists, but is treated as not existing until the `let` statement has successfully executed.

From the ES6 spec:

> The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is evaluated.

In simple terms, the variable has been created, but cannot be accessed because its "LexicalBinding" has not been evaluated.

Using the console, you have created a situation where:

- The `let` statement has not successfully executed (so it is a `ReferenceError` to try to access its variable).
- You have two `let`s for the same variable name within the same scope (so the second one creates a syntax error). (n.b. Simply having two `let`s in the same scope would cause the code to fail at the *compilation stage*, before the first one even had a chance to try to execute if you weren't entering the code a little bit at a time into the console).

This is a situation that could not occur in ordinary code.

Ordinarily, you would not be able to continue running statements in the scope where an error has been thrown, so the first bullet would be impossible. The console allows you to do that.

It would be further impossible under ordinary circumstances because the code would fail at the *compilation stage*, before the first `let` statement could even try to run.

So that's why you're getting an error in both cases.

Comment: Now I understand everything about my issue, awesome to know how this statement works, thanks @JLRishe

Comment: Note that this behavior appears to be browser-specific. In Firefox's developer tools, for instance, after executing `let myVariable = "".boom()` you can still assign a value to `myVariable` without issue.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this question is actually really interesting and I *may* have found an answer for it.

The phenomenon you are describing is most likely related to **how** the Javascript engine compiles your code. While it may seem otherwise to the programmer, the compilation consists of several steps and are executed at different stages during the process. So, depending on what kind of error you have in your code, this process can terminate at any point of the process.

So, if your object creation is flawed (`config` is undefined) but the syntax per se is fine (from a language standpoint) you'll get an error later on in the compilation process compared to something that is illegal in Javascript generally.

See, `let` is quite sophisticated because it prevents variable naming collisions (hence the `Indentifier 'myClassInstance' has already been defined` error). This is unlike `var` which does not have this feature.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let):

> Redeclaring the same variable within the same function or block scope
>   raises a SyntaxError.
>
> ```
> if (x) {
>   let foo;
>   let foo; // SyntaxError thrown.
> }
> ```
>
> In ECMAScript 2015, let will hoist the variable to the top of the
>   block. However, referencing the variable in the block before the
>   variable declaration results in a ReferenceError. The variable is in a
>   "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the declaration
>   is processed.

---

#### TL;DR

The following code will trigger an error earlier on during the compilation process

```
let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
let myClassInstance = '123';
```

compared to:

```
let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
myClassInstance = '123';
```

This is because the former is illegal syntax in Javascript, whereas the latter isn't. In the latter case the code will compile fine, but will fail in runtime because the argument is undefined.

---

**EDIT:**

I found this [blog](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-guide-to-javascript-engines-for-idiots/) and is quite an interesting read. Snippet:

> Huh? In simple terms, this JavaScript engine takes your source code, breaks it up into strings (a.k.a. lexes it), takes those strings and converts them into bytecode that a compiler can understand, and then executes it.

Another deep-dive tutorial [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/).

Comment: Yea, I knew about compiling js and how it is getting processed, however thanks for pointing out that var allows overwriting variable because it doesn't care about that, I didn't thought about it at first.